# How can I deactivate the back button of android?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to avoid that the android back button works when someone press it. My goal is that only the back button on the top of screen works.

I tried fix it with WillPopScope, however, the button is still working...

I hope that when I press the back button of android, nothing happens. Somebody can help me with this problem?

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:rating_bar/rating_bar.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:cruke_app/ui/map.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

class ChosenOption extends StatefulWidget {
  final String option;
  final DocumentSnapshot document;

  ChosenOption({Key key, @required this.document, this.option}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChosenOptionState createState() => _ChosenOptionState();
}

class _ChosenOptionState extends State<ChosenOption> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  String _mapStyle;
  static const LatLng _center = const LatLng(45.521563, -122.677433);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    rootBundle.loadString('assets/map_style.txt').then((string) {
      _mapStyle = string;
    });
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
    mapController.setMapStyle(_mapStyle);
    _controller.complete(controller);
  }
  Future<bool> _willPopCallback() async{
    return false;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double _rating = 0;
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _willPopCallback,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  CarouselSlider(
                    height: 200.0,
                    items: [1,2,3,4,5].map((i) {
                      return Builder(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: NetworkImage(widget.document["image"]),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Text('$i', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),)
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.red, size: 35,),
                    onPressed: (){
                      Navigator.pop(context, false);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 13.0), 
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                      child: Text(widget.document["title"], 
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, 
                      fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15,
                      child: RawMaterialButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.favorite,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 20.0,
                        ),
                        shape: CircleBorder(),
                        elevation: 2.0,
                        fillColor: Colors.red,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 13.0),
                    child: Icon(Icons.star, size: 18.0, color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                    child: RatingBar(
                      onRatingChanged: (rating) => setState(() => widget.document["rating"] == rating),
                      filledIcon: Icons.star,
                      emptyIcon: Icons.star_border,
                      halfFilledIcon: Icons.star_half,
                      isHalfAllowed: true,
                      filledColor: Colors.yellow,
                      emptyColor: Colors.grey,
                      halfFilledColor: Colors.yellow, 
                      size: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                    child: Text(widget.document["avaliations"].toString()+"   |  ", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 10.0),),
                  ),

                  Text(widget.document["city"], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 10.0),), 
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(13.0),
                child: Text(widget.document["text"]),
              ),
              Divider(),
              Text("Avaliações", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,),),
              buildEvaluation(_rating, "images/restaurant.jpg", "Leandro", "Minas Gerais - MG", "6 dias atrás"),
              buildEvaluation(_rating, "images/restaurant.jpg", "Leandro", "Minas Gerais - MG", "10 dias atrás"),
              buildEvaluation(_rating, "images/restaurant.jpg", "Leandro", "MInas Gerais - MG", "16 dias atrás"),
              Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                        child: Text("Avaliar este Restaurante", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                        child: RatingBar(
                          onRatingChanged: (rating) => setState(() => _rating = rating),
                          filledIcon: Icons.star,
                          emptyIcon: Icons.star_border,
                          halfFilledIcon: Icons.star_half,
                          isHalfAllowed: true,
                          filledColor: Colors.yellow,
                          emptyColor: Colors.black,
                          halfFilledColor: Colors.yellow, 
                          size: 20,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 300.0,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50.0),
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            suffixIcon: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(end: 12.0),
                              child: Icon(Icons.send, color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                            hintText: "Comentar...",
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 15.0),
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 220.0, bottom: 5.0),
                        child: Text("Local no mapa",
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 340.0,
                        height: 200.0,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              offset: Offset(1.0, 1.0),
                              blurRadius: 10.0,
                            ),
                          ],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        ), 
                        child: GoogleMap(
                          mapType: MapType.normal,
                          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                            target: _center,
                            zoom: 18.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ), 
                      RaisedButton.icon(   
                        onPressed: (){
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CrukeMap()),
                          );
                        },
                        label: Text(
                          'TRAÇAR ROTA',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),               
                        ),
                        color: Colors.red,
                        icon: Icon(Icons.directions, color: Colors.white),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 40.0),
                            child: Icon(Icons.place, color: Colors.red, size: 18,),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 40.0),
                            child: Text("R. Sete de Setembro, Porto Seguro - BA, 45810-000", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),),
                          ),
                        ],  
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 10.0),
                            child: Icon(Icons.local_phone, color: Colors.red, size: 18,),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 10.0),
                            child: Text("(73)99906-3724", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),),
                          ),
                        ],  
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 50.0),
                            child: Icon(Icons.timer, color: Colors.red, size: 18,),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 50.0),
                            child: Text("Horário de Funcionamento: 12:00 às 20:00", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),),
                          ),
                        ],  
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),   
                ],
              ),
            ], 
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildEvaluation(double _rating, String image, String name, String location, String time){
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 30.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 80.0,
                  width: 80.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      image: ExactAssetImage(image),
                    ),
                )),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                child: RatingBar(
                  onRatingChanged: (rating) => setState(() => _rating = rating),
                  filledIcon: Icons.star,
                  emptyIcon: Icons.star_border,
                  halfFilledIcon: Icons.star_half,
                  isHalfAllowed: true,
                  filledColor: Colors.yellow,
                  emptyColor: Colors.grey,
                  halfFilledColor: Colors.yellow, 
                  size: 20,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                child: Text(time, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 10.0),),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 110.0, left: 5.0),
              child: Text(name),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, left: 10.0),
              child: Text(location),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 140.0, top: 70.0, bottom: 10.0),
          width: 200.0,
          child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt" +
          "ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat." ), 
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer for this, but if this is for a real app, you should know you can have apps rejected for altering "expected behaviors" of the platform.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this work:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyHomePage()
      ),
      routes: {
        'home': (context) => MyHomePage(),
        'page1': (context) => Page1(),
      }
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
       child: Card(
         child: Center(
                    child: Column(
             children: <Widget>[
               IconButton(
                 icon: Icon(Icons.transit_enterexit),
                 onPressed: () { Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'page1');}
                 )
             ],
             ),
         )
       )
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  Page1({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _Page1State createState() => _Page1State();
}

Future<bool> controlBackButton() async {
  return false;
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () {return controlBackButton();},
          child: Container(
         child: Card(
           child:  ListTile(
             title: Text('Hello'),
             subtitle: Text('Click home to go back'),
             trailing: IconButton(
               icon: Icon(Icons.home),
               onPressed: ()  { Navigator.pop(context); }

             ),
           ),
         )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```